# API Calls limit and How to handle

Tags: javascript, api, nuxt.js

I'm planning develop a side project where I get multiple third party API's, using Nuxt.js
The API has a limit of 7500 calls per day.
I have to have a call on 2 apis every minute, 1 call on other Api per day and other Api call twice a month.
So lets assume that I have 1000 online users, is there a way to make api calls without thinking about the amount of users that are using the website? what I mean is only calling the api's once without making the call for each user.

Comment: It's probably possible. Did you try anything? Please share your efforts

Comment: You could cache the responses for same/ similar calls.

Comment: Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You can use the approch that next.js (i know you use nuxt but you can try something similar) provides https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation. Basically you can generate your static content (fetching an api) at build time. Next also provide the possibility to revalidate cache. In this way you can predict the number of calls and you can also serve the same content to all users 1 or 1000 with a single api call.